# How do you make Me.DialogResult a string in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, dialog

How to do I make a custom `InputBox`, or more importantly: how do I make `Me.DialogResult` as string?

This is what i tried:

```
Public Function Display(ByVal Information As String) As DialogResult
        Dim inputbox22 As New CustomInputDialog
        inputbox22.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Return inputbox22.DialogResult()
End Function

Private Function strtest() as integer
    Me.DialogResult = TextBox1
End Function
```

I have been working on this for hours, and definitely don't want to use `InputBox()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DialogResult will always remain one of values `vbYes`, `vbNo`, `vbOk`, `vbCancel`, `vbAbort`, `vbRetry`, `vbIgnore`. They are actually numbers, you **cannot** pass text as DialogResult.

You can always create your input form like new form with for example:

- text box
- button for confirmation
- button for cancellation

Then call your form using [ShowDialog() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and after it got closed, you can read value of the text box. See code example of the entire process in the above MSDN article.